# Existing 3-way circuit trips breaker

Tags: electrical

I'm sleuthing out a mysterious short in a 3-way circuit and could use some advice.  I have an ordinary 15A breaker with a feed to our kitchen pendants, and some outlets in the room.  The lights are switched with a 3-way circuit that out of the blue has started to pop the breaker when it is turned on.  The circuit carries a load to both outlets and another light.  I have been able to determine that when the 3-way switch is turned on it creates a short buzz near one of the outlets and then the breaker trips.  I replaced the breaker, but that did not fix the issue.  I then isolated the problem down to the pendant lights feed and the 3-way circuit.  This appeared out of the blue today, and baffles me.

I pulled and examined both switches and they appear to be fine.  The only thing I felt needed to be done was to tighten down the terminal screws, as they were fully extended.  The wires are inserted into quick-wire slots.  I debated about replacing the switches, but that would be just another easter-egg hunt, and not at all certain they would be at fault.  Does anyone have a thought on what to check next?  I find it strange that the buzzing noise is not in the 3-way circuit - or at least I don't think so.

Comment: If it's creating a buzz near an outlet, have you tried replacing the outlet? It's not normal for outlets to buzz.

Comment: Have you hung anything on the walls or otherwise drilled into the walls recently?  Even if done in an adjacent room a wire could have been nicked, causing a short.

Comment: Turns out not to be the outlet that is buzzing as it is live and well.  There has not been anything done work wise in this house for a long, long time.  I went under the house and had the wife flip the breaker on and tried to listen for where the buzz was coming from, and all I could sense was somewhere above me.  Please see my other comment to another poster.

Answer (score 2):

Grrr  hahaha grrr hahaha grrr 
aaa
Solved - and I have a very red face.  Turns out that several years ago I replaced a light bulb in one of the pendants.  When it did not light up, I determined that the base of the bulb was not making contact with the pin in the seat of the socket.  To help it out I put a penny in the socket and presto - things worked (foolish me!).  Turns out that the penny moved to one side when a new bulb was installed and gradually made contact with the socket wall - not good!

So, after a breaker swap, two 3-way switches and a lot of bafflement, I have only myself to blame.  I'm lucky indeed that was all that happened, lesson learned as things could have turned out much worse.  Enjoy the laugh - it's on me!

Comment: A penny saved is a penny zapped!